# Question regarding transit visa in Germany for an Indian citizen?

Tags: airport-transfer, indian-citizens

I am travelling from Toronto to new Delhi. I have a valid Indian passport and a valid Canada student visa. I have stops at Munich and Frankfurt for 1 hour and 1.5 hours respectively.
Do I need any kind of transit or airport transit visa?

Comment: You must add your citizenship otherwise we can't answer.

Comment: Having an Indian passport, I thik it is sage to assume he is an Indian citizen. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to travel between Munich and Frankfurt, an [Airport Transit visa](http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4002756/Daten/3548245/airport_transit.pdf) is not sufficient, you need to apply for a full Schengen visa. You also can't benefit from the exemption granted to Canadian visa holders since it applies only to Airport Transit visas.